# Tokening a string with multiple character separator

Tags: python, regex, tokenize

I am trying to tokenize an expression with the following rules:

- The separators are '}}' and '{{'
- The strings between separators should be kept intact (excluding single spaces that are discarded (could be done in the parser)
- The separators can be embedded and the order should be kept
- Single occurences of '{' and '}' should be kept untouched and not used as separators (see last test).
- There should be no empty strings in the result (could be done in the parser)

The couple of exceptions (marked in parens) can be done by post-processing the (correct) result in the parse. The result will be fed to a recursive descent parser.

Here are a few trials, which are not passing the unit tests that I have included. The `find_all` function is the closest to match but still manages to drop some parts. I am not using `re.split()` in the code below (it would keep the empty strings), but I tried it with no better luck. I am hoping that regex will work to avoid scanning the strings character by character in my code.

```
def tokenize_search(line):
    token_pat = re.compile(r'({{)([^{(?!{)]*|[^}(?!})]*)(}})')
    tokens = re.search(token_pat, line).groups()
    return list (tokens)

def tokenize_findall(line):
    token_pat = re.compile(r'({{)([^{(?!{)]*|[^}(?!})]*)(}})')
    tokens = re.findall(token_pat, line)
    return tokens

def check(a1, a2):
    print(a1 == a2)

def main():
    check(tokenize_search('{{}}'), ['{{', '}}'])
    check(tokenize_search('aaa {{}}'), ['{{', '}}'])
    check(tokenize_search('{{aaa}}'), ['{{', 'aaa', '}}'])
    check(tokenize_search('{{aa}} {{bbb}}'), ['{{', 'aa', '}}', '{{', 'bbb', '}}'])
    check(tokenize_search('{{aaa {{ bb }} }}'), ['{{', 'aaa ', '{{', ' bb ', '}}', '}}'])
    check(tokenize_search('{{aa {{ bbb {{ c }} }} }}'), ['{{', 'aa ', '{{', ' bbb ', '{{', ' c ', '}}', '}}', '}}'])
    check(tokenize_search('{{a{a}{{ b{b}b {{ c }} }} }}'), ['{{', 'a{a}', '{{', ' b{b}b ', '{{', ' c ', '}}', '}}', '}}'])
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Olivier for providing a solution that works. I am still hoping a regex solution could work if I could better understand regex lookout. If I use the `tokenize_finditer` method below, it passes the tests and all it does is filling the `skipped` groups with what's in-between (at the exception of the space which I could have post-processed to make code simpler). So my hope it that I could add an `or` clause to the `'({{)|(}})'` regex that says: `or get any character followed by any character that doesn't match '}}' or '{{'. Unfortunately, I can't succeed writing this matcher. I've seen examples of regex able to even do recursive matching, and because this is not recursive, it sounds even more doable.

```
def tokenize_finditer(line):
    token_pat = re.compile(r'({{)|(}})')
    result = []
    if re.search(token_pat, line):
        prev = len(line)
        for match in re.finditer(token_pat, line):
            start, end = match.span()
            if start > prev:
                expr = line[prev:start]
                if not expr.isspace():
                    result.append(expr)
            prev = end
            result.append(match.group())

    return result
```

Comment: You should be writing a rudimentary parser to handle this.  Regex probably isn't the best tool to be using here, I think.

Comment: Your second rule is contradicting your expected result for test 4. The space is not kept intact.

Comment: Thanks for catching this, this is a typo. I updated the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not quite a [parentheses matching problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/546457/5079316), but it is close enough for me to recommend not trying to solve it with a regex.

Since what you want to do is to *partition* you string with the given separators, then we can write a solution based on a `partition` function with some tweaking to fit all rules.

```
import re

def partition(s, sep):
    tokens = s.split(sep)

    # Intersperse the separator betweem found tokens
    partition = [sep] * (2 * len(tokens) - 1)
    partition[::2] = tokens

    # We remove empty and whitespace-only tokens
    return [tk for tk in partition if tk and not tk.isspace()]


def tokenize_search(line):
    # Only keep what is inside brackets
    line = re.search(r'{{.*}}', line).group() or ''

    return [tk for sub in partition(line, '{{') for tk in partition(sub, '}}')]
```

The above code passes all tests. You will need to feed that result to a parser to check parentheses matching.

Comment: Nice touch about using the 3 parameter of a slice. I capitulated about figuring out the regex because it seems not possible without using recursion.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Olivier Melançon's partitioning approach is the way to go. However, there is still some use for a regex, e.g. checking if the pattern in question is properly balanced or extracting the balanced from a larger string (as indicated by the 2nd example).

Doing so requires a recursive regex like that:

```
{{((?>(?:(?!{{|}}).)++|(?R))*+)}}
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/EUwMHq/1)

Since Python re module does not support regex recursion you will need to rely on the alternative [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module to make use of it.

To further process the match result, you would need to look at the inner part in `$1` and go deeper one level at a time, e.g. [`\w+|{{((?>(?:(?!(?:{{|}})).)++|(?R))*+)}}`](https://regex101.com/r/EUwMHq/1) but that's cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

just got your message on twitter :) I know I'm 2 months late to the party, but I have a couple of new ideas in case you're interested.

I looked over the examples and noticed that you could pretty much get away with matching and capturing all "{{" or "}}" or "a token that is in the middle of a {{ }} pair". Fortunately, this is rather simple to express:

```
/({{|}}|(?:(?!{{|}})[^ ])+(?!({{(?2)*?}}|(?:(?!{{|}}).)*)*$))/g
```

[On regex101 using your examples](https://regex101.com/r/CDUk9B/1/)

"in the middle of a {{ }} pair" is the only tricky part. For this, I used that negative lookahead to make sure we were NOT in a position that is followed by a balanced number of (potentially nested) {{ }} pairs, then the end of the string. This would, *for well-balanced input*, ensure all matched tokens are inside {{ }} pairs.

Now, you ask, what about the "well-balanced input" part? If the input is invalid, then an example such as "aaa}}" would yield `["aaa", "}}"]` as a result. Not ideal. You could validate the input separately; or, if you wish to turn this into a untameable monster, then you can go for something like this:

```
/(?:^(?!({{(?1)*?}}|(?:(?!{{|}}).)*)*+$)(*COMMIT)(*F))?({{|}}|(?:(?!{{|}})[^ ])+(?!({{(?3)*?}}|(?:(?!{{|}}).)*)*+$))/g
```

[Unleashed on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/CDUk9B/2)

This is really just for show. I agree with the other suggestions recommending a parser or some other more maintainable tool. But if you've seen my blog then you understand I have an affinity for these monsters :)